# intuition on what PDEs mean "physically".

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I've taken PDE/ODE classes and now I'm starting to do work that requires knowledge about them but I've never felt comfortable.  I've learned about laplace/heat/wave equation and other examples, but I can rarely see a PDE/ODE and be able to translate the equations into a "physical" interpretation to gain some intuition as to what the system of equations is representing.  I see that if $u:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is some differentiable function then $\nabla u$ is the gradient, which essentially is a vector valued function that points in the direction of fastest increase for $u$.  This is probably the most basic example, but then we get to, for example, the laplacian $\Delta u$, and even though I know it's the sum of the squared second derivatives, I have no clue how to relate this to the world besides the mathematical definition.  Another example comes from Ulrich Hornungs book on homogenization, where he starts with the ODE:

$\frac{d}{dx}(a(x)\frac{d}{dx}u(x))=0$ for $0<x<1$,

$u(x)=0$ for $x=0$,

$u(x)=1$ when $x=1$.

He says this is a one dimensional diffusion problem and that the differential equation requires that the flux $q(x)=-a(x)\frac{d}{dx}u(x)$ be constant.  I see why $q(x)$ must be constant, but why in the world is this the flux and how does this describe diffusion?

I feel like perhaps my vector calculus is just not where it needs to be, but I never saw the biggest picture when I took multivariable calculus a while ago.  Is there any book that goes through the mathematics of the vector calculus/PDEs but also explains the physics/intuition behind what everything talks about?  I suppose I'm just at the point where I don't know what I need to study to make myself more comfortable with the subject.

Comment: The advection equation generalizes in some useful ways which are relevant to what you are asking about here. In particular, $u_t + \nabla \cdot v = 0$ says that $u$ is a field of particles moving at velocity $v$. That $v$ might depend on $x,t$ or even back on $u$. As an important example, when $v=-\nabla u$ you have the heat equation. This is because of Fick's law, which says that diffusing particles move directly towards areas of lower concentration.

Comment: Your example here is again an example of this, where you have a stationary solution to a heat-like equation, but where this additional function $a$ makes the character of the diffusion (its direction and rate) depend on $x$.

Comment: As for deriving the advection equation, the divergence theorem is the heart of the proof: the total flux out of a region is the surface integral of the velocity field against the outer normal of the region. The divergence theorem says that this is equal to the integral of the divergence of the velocity field over the volume of the region. You then get the advection equation by restricting attention to small regions.

Comment: The former picture is fairly intuitive; a picture should clarify it pretty well. The latter picture has never been so intuitive to me, but we have the divergence theorem, so it is enough to understand one or the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer: The Laplacian measures how a function changes “on average” as you move away from a given point. It’s rotationally invariant, so, for example, $f_{xx}+f_{yy}=0$ describes a property of a function on the Euclidean plane that doesn’t depend on the choice of Euclidean coordinates.